# Getting Invalid LatLng object when trying to map coordinates using leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to figure out how I can loop each of the coordinates,

```
    <div class="map-container" id="mapid"></div>

    <ul class="plot">
        <li class="markers" data-lattitude="-40.99497" data-longitude="174.50808">Text 1</li>
        <li class="markers" data-lattitude="-41.30269" data-longitude="173.63696">Text 2</li>
        <li class="markers" data-lattitude="-41.49413" data-longitude="173.5421">Text 3</li>
        <li class="markers" data-lattitude="-40.98585" data-longitude="174.50659">Text 4</li>
        <li class="markers" data-lattitude="-40.93163" data-longitude="173.81726">Text 5</li>
    </ul>
```

add them to an array, plot them on the map with the popup text shown. Below is an error that I can't seem to solve. not sure which part of the code is wrong.

> leaflet.js:5 Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (e, x)

Below is the sample of the code that I have been working on.

```js
        var map = L.map('mapid', {

            fullscreenControl: {
                pseudoFullscreen: false // if true, fullscreen to page width and height
            },
            
        }).setView([30.539255791073, 58.383450508118], 5);

        map.createPane('labels');
        map.getPane('labels').style.zIndex = 650;
        map.getPane('labels').style.pointerEvents = 'none';

        var positron = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                noWrap: true,
                maxZoom : 10
        }).addTo(map);

        var positronLabels = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                pane: 'labels',
                noWrap: true,
                maxZoom : 3
        }).addTo(map);

        var southWest = L.latLng(-89.98155760646617, -180),
            northEast = L.latLng(89.99346179538875, 180),
            bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

            map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
            map.on('drag', function() {
                map.panInsideBounds(bounds, { animate: false });
            });


        var plot = [];

        $('.plot > .markers').each(function() {
            plot.push($(this).text(), $(this).data('lattitude'),  $(this).data('longitude')
            );
        });

        console.log( plot );

        for ( var i = 0; i < plot.length; i++ ) {
            marker = new L.marker([plot[i][1], plot[i][2]]).bindPopup(plot[i][0], {autoClose:false}).addTo(map).openPopup();
        }
```

```css
/* required styles */

.leaflet-pane,
.leaflet-tile,
.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow,
.leaflet-tile-container,
.leaflet-pane > svg,
.leaflet-pane > canvas,
.leaflet-zoom-box,
.leaflet-image-layer,
.leaflet-layer {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 }
.leaflet-container {
 overflow: hidden;
 }
.leaflet-tile,
.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow {
 -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
         user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-drag: none;
 }
/* Safari renders non-retina tile on retina better with this, but Chrome is worse */
.leaflet-safari .leaflet-tile {
 image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
 }
/* hack that prevents hw layers "stretching" when loading new tiles */
.leaflet-safari .leaflet-tile-container {
 width: 1600px;
 height: 1600px;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
 }
.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow {
 display: block;
 }
/* .leaflet-container svg: reset svg max-width decleration shipped in Joomla! (joomla.org) 3.x */
/* .leaflet-container img: map is broken in FF if you have max-width: 100% on tiles */
.leaflet-container .leaflet-overlay-pane svg,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-marker-pane img,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-shadow-pane img,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-tile-pane img,
.leaflet-container img.leaflet-image-layer,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-tile {
 max-width: none !important;
 max-height: none !important;
 }

.leaflet-container.leaflet-touch-zoom {
 -ms-touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
 touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
 }
.leaflet-container.leaflet-touch-drag {
 -ms-touch-action: pinch-zoom;
 /* Fallback for FF which doesn't support pinch-zoom */
 touch-action: none;
 touch-action: pinch-zoom;
}
.leaflet-container.leaflet-touch-drag.leaflet-touch-zoom {
 -ms-touch-action: none;
 touch-action: none;
}
.leaflet-container {
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.leaflet-container a {
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(51, 181, 229, 0.4);
}
.leaflet-tile {
 filter: inherit;
 visibility: hidden;
 }
.leaflet-tile-loaded {
 visibility: inherit;
 }
.leaflet-zoom-box {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
 z-index: 800;
 }
/* workaround for https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=888319 */
.leaflet-overlay-pane svg {
 -moz-user-select: none;
 }

.leaflet-pane         { z-index: 400; }

.leaflet-tile-pane    { z-index: 200; }
.leaflet-overlay-pane { z-index: 400; }
.leaflet-shadow-pane  { z-index: 500; }
.leaflet-marker-pane  { z-index: 600; }
.leaflet-tooltip-pane   { z-index: 650; }
.leaflet-popup-pane   { z-index: 700; }

.leaflet-map-pane canvas { z-index: 100; }
.leaflet-map-pane svg    { z-index: 200; }

.leaflet-vml-shape {
 width: 1px;
 height: 1px;
 }
.lvml {
 behavior: url(#default#VML);
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 }


/* control positioning */

.leaflet-control {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 800;
 pointer-events: visiblePainted; /* IE 9-10 doesn't have auto */
 pointer-events: auto;
 }
.leaflet-top,
.leaflet-bottom {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1000;
 pointer-events: none;
 }
.leaflet-top {
 top: 0;
 }
.leaflet-right {
 right: 0;
 }
.leaflet-bottom {
 bottom: 0;
 }
.leaflet-left {
 left: 0;
 }
.leaflet-control {
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 }
.leaflet-right .leaflet-control {
 float: right;
 }
.leaflet-top .leaflet-control {
 margin-top: 10px;
 }
.leaflet-bottom .leaflet-control {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
.leaflet-left .leaflet-control {
 margin-left: 10px;
 }
.leaflet-right .leaflet-control {
 margin-right: 10px;
 }


/* zoom and fade animations */

.leaflet-fade-anim .leaflet-tile {
 will-change: opacity;
 }
.leaflet-fade-anim .leaflet-popup {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
         transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
 }
.leaflet-fade-anim .leaflet-map-pane .leaflet-popup {
 opacity: 1;
 }
.leaflet-zoom-animated {
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
     -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
         transform-origin: 0 0;
 }
.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-zoom-animated {
 will-change: transform;
 }
.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-zoom-animated {
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0,0,0.25,1);
    -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0,0,0.25,1);
         transition:         transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0,0,0.25,1);
 }
.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-tile,
.leaflet-pan-anim .leaflet-tile {
 -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
         transition: none;
 }

.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-zoom-hide {
 visibility: hidden;
 }


/* cursors */

.leaflet-interactive {
 cursor: pointer;
 }
.leaflet-grab {
 cursor: -webkit-grab;
 cursor:    -moz-grab;
 cursor:         grab;
 }
.leaflet-crosshair,
.leaflet-crosshair .leaflet-interactive {
 cursor: crosshair;
 }
.leaflet-popup-pane,
.leaflet-control {
 cursor: auto;
 }
.leaflet-dragging .leaflet-grab,
.leaflet-dragging .leaflet-grab .leaflet-interactive,
.leaflet-dragging .leaflet-marker-draggable {
 cursor: move;
 cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
 cursor:    -moz-grabbing;
 cursor:         grabbing;
 }

/* marker & overlays interactivity */
.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow,
.leaflet-image-layer,
.leaflet-pane > svg path,
.leaflet-tile-container {
 pointer-events: none;
 }

.leaflet-marker-icon.leaflet-interactive,
.leaflet-image-layer.leaflet-interactive,
.leaflet-pane > svg path.leaflet-interactive {
 pointer-events: visiblePainted; /* IE 9-10 doesn't have auto */
 pointer-events: auto;
 }

/* visual tweaks */

.leaflet-container {
 background: #ddd;
 outline: 0;
 }
.leaflet-container a {
 color: #0078A8;
 }
.leaflet-container a.leaflet-active {
 outline: 2px solid orange;
 }
.leaflet-zoom-box {
 border: 2px dotted #38f;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 }


/* general typography */
.leaflet-container {
 font: 12px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 }


/* general toolbar styles */

.leaflet-bar {
 box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
 border-radius: 4px;
 }
.leaflet-bar a,
.leaflet-bar a:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 26px;
 height: 26px;
 line-height: 26px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 }
.leaflet-bar a,
.leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 display: block;
 }
.leaflet-bar a:hover {
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 }
.leaflet-bar a:first-child {
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 }
.leaflet-bar a:last-child {
 border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom: none;
 }
.leaflet-bar a.leaflet-disabled {
 cursor: default;
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 color: #bbb;
 }

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar a {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 }
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar a:first-child {
 border-top-left-radius: 2px;
 border-top-right-radius: 2px;
 }
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar a:last-child {
 border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
 }

/* zoom control */

.leaflet-control-zoom-in,
.leaflet-control-zoom-out {
 font: bold 18px 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
 text-indent: 1px;
 }

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-zoom-in, .leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-zoom-out  {
 font-size: 22px;
 }


/* layers control */

.leaflet-control-layers {
 box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 5px;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
 background-image: url(images/layers.png);
 width: 36px;
 height: 36px;
 }
.leaflet-retina .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
 background-image: url(images/layers-2x.png);
 background-size: 26px 26px;
 }
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
 width: 44px;
 height: 44px;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers .leaflet-control-layers-list,
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
 display: none;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded .leaflet-control-layers-list {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded {
 padding: 6px 10px 6px 6px;
 color: #333;
 background: #fff;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-scrollbar {
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 padding-right: 5px;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-selector {
 margin-top: 2px;
 position: relative;
 top: 1px;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers label {
 display: block;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-separator {
 height: 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
 margin: 5px -10px 5px -6px;
 }

/* Default icon URLs */
.leaflet-default-icon-path {
 background-image: url(images/marker-icon.png);
 }


/* attribution and scale controls */

.leaflet-container .leaflet-control-attribution {
 background: #fff;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
 margin: 0;
 }
.leaflet-control-attribution,
.leaflet-control-scale-line {
 padding: 0 5px;
 color: #333;
 }
.leaflet-control-attribution a {
 text-decoration: none;
 }
.leaflet-control-attribution a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 }
.leaflet-container .leaflet-control-attribution,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-control-scale {
 font-size: 11px;
 }
.leaflet-left .leaflet-control-scale {
 margin-left: 5px;
 }
.leaflet-bottom .leaflet-control-scale {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
.leaflet-control-scale-line {
 border: 2px solid #777;
 border-top: none;
 line-height: 1.1;
 padding: 2px 5px 1px;
 font-size: 11px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;

 background: #fff;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 }
.leaflet-control-scale-line:not(:first-child) {
 border-top: 2px solid #777;
 border-bottom: none;
 margin-top: -2px;
 }
.leaflet-control-scale-line:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #777;
 }

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-attribution,
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers,
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar {
 box-shadow: none;
 }
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers,
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar {
 border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 background-clip: padding-box;
 }


/* popup */

.leaflet-popup {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
 padding: 1px;
 text-align: left;
 border-radius: 12px;
 }
.leaflet-popup-content {
 margin: 13px 19px;
 line-height: 1.4;
 }
.leaflet-popup-content p {
 margin: 18px 0;
 }
.leaflet-popup-tip-container {
 width: 40px;
 height: 20px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 pointer-events: none;
 }
.leaflet-popup-tip {
 width: 17px;
 height: 17px;
 padding: 1px;

 margin: -10px auto 0;

 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
         transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,
.leaflet-popup-tip {
 background: white;
 color: #333;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 }
.leaflet-container a.leaflet-popup-close-button {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 4px 4px 0 0;
 border: none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 18px;
 height: 14px;
 font: 16px/14px Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
 color: #c3c3c3;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: transparent;
 }
.leaflet-container a.leaflet-popup-close-button:hover {
 color: #999;
 }
.leaflet-popup-scrolled {
 overflow: auto;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
 }

.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
 zoom: 1;
 }
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-tip {
 width: 24px;
 margin: 0 auto;

 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.70710678, M12=0.70710678, M21=-0.70710678, M22=0.70710678)";
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.70710678, M12=0.70710678, M21=-0.70710678, M22=0.70710678);
 }
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-tip-container {
 margin-top: -1px;
 }

.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-control-zoom,
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-control-layers,
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-tip {
 border: 1px solid #999;
 }


/* div icon */

.leaflet-div-icon {
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #666;
 }


/* Tooltip */
/* Base styles for the element that has a tooltip */
.leaflet-tooltip {
 position: absolute;
 padding: 6px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 3px;
 color: #222;
 white-space: nowrap;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 pointer-events: none;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 }
.leaflet-tooltip.leaflet-clickable {
 cursor: pointer;
 pointer-events: auto;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-top:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-bottom:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-left:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-right:before {
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 border: 6px solid transparent;
 background: transparent;
 content: "";
 }

/* Directions */

.leaflet-tooltip-bottom {
 margin-top: 6px;
}
.leaflet-tooltip-top {
 margin-top: -6px;
}
.leaflet-tooltip-bottom:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-top:before {
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -6px;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-top:before {
 bottom: 0;
 margin-bottom: -12px;
 border-top-color: #fff;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-bottom:before {
 top: 0;
 margin-top: -12px;
 margin-left: -6px;
 border-bottom-color: #fff;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-left {
 margin-left: -6px;
}
.leaflet-tooltip-right {
 margin-left: 6px;
}
.leaflet-tooltip-left:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-right:before {
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -6px;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-left:before {
 right: 0;
 margin-right: -12px;
 border-left-color: #fff;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-right:before {
 left: 0;
 margin-left: -12px;
 border-right-color: #fff;
 }



/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}




html, body {
    width  : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}

.map-container {
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant@latest/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js"></script>


        <div class="map-container" id="mapid"></div>

        <ul class="plot">
            <li class="markers" data-lattitude="-40.99497" data-longitude="174.50808">Text 1</li>
            <li class="markers" data-lattitude="-41.30269" data-longitude="173.63696">Text 2</li>
            <li class="markers" data-lattitude="-41.49413" data-longitude="173.5421">Text 3</li>
            <li class="markers" data-lattitude="-40.98585" data-longitude="174.50659">Text 4</li>
            <li class="markers" data-lattitude="-40.93163" data-longitude="173.81726">Text 5</li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Silly question, what do I click on the map (or in the snippet) to generate the error you mention?

Comment: @CertainPerformance the error isn't triggered by a click or an event. The error is already shown on the console when you try running it.

Comment: Oh, whoops, you're right, I was expecting to see something in the *stack snippet* console, but it's not logged there, it's only logged to the *browser* console :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
plot.push(
  $(this).text(),
  $(this).data('lattitude'),
  $(this).data('longitude')
);
```

You're pushing *three items* to the `plot` array, resulting in the `plot` array looking something like this:

```
["Text 1", -40.99497, 174.50808, "Text 2", -41.30269, 173.63696
```

Later, when you try to iterate over the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < plot.length; i++) {
  marker = new L.marker([plot[i][1], plot[i][2]]).bindPopup(plot[i][0], {
```

You're accessing the second and third index of the *string* (the first element in `plot`), not the second and third index of an *array* (resulting in the `e` and `x` you see, which came from `text`).

Instead, push an *array* of those three items to `plot`:

```
plot.push([
  $(this).text(),
  $(this).data('lattitude'),
  $(this).data('longitude')
]);
```

```js
var map = L.map('mapid', {

  fullscreenControl: {
    pseudoFullscreen: false // if true, fullscreen to page width and height
  },

}).setView([30.539255791073, 58.383450508118], 5);

map.createPane('labels');
map.getPane('labels').style.zIndex = 650;
map.getPane('labels').style.pointerEvents = 'none';

var positron = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  noWrap: true,
  maxZoom: 10
}).addTo(map);

var positronLabels = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  pane: 'labels',
  noWrap: true,
  maxZoom: 3
}).addTo(map);

var southWest = L.latLng(-89.98155760646617, -180),
  northEast = L.latLng(89.99346179538875, 180),
  bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
map.on('drag', function() {
  map.panInsideBounds(bounds, {
    animate: false
  });
});


var plot = [];

$('.plot > .markers').each(function() {
  plot.push([$(this).text(), $(this).data('lattitude'), $(this).data('longitude')]);
});

console.log(plot);

for (var i = 0; i < plot.length; i++) {
  marker = new L.marker([plot[i][1], plot[i][2]]).bindPopup(plot[i][0], {
    autoClose: false
  }).addTo(map).openPopup();
}
```

```css
/* required styles */

.leaflet-pane,
.leaflet-tile,
.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow,
.leaflet-tile-container,
.leaflet-pane>svg,
.leaflet-pane>canvas,
.leaflet-zoom-box,
.leaflet-image-layer,
.leaflet-layer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.leaflet-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.leaflet-tile,
.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
}


/* Safari renders non-retina tile on retina better with this, but Chrome is worse */

.leaflet-safari .leaflet-tile {
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
}


/* hack that prevents hw layers "stretching" when loading new tiles */

.leaflet-safari .leaflet-tile-container {
  width: 1600px;
  height: 1600px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow {
  display: block;
}


/* .leaflet-container svg: reset svg max-width decleration shipped in Joomla! (joomla.org) 3.x */


/* .leaflet-container img: map is broken in FF if you have max-width: 100% on tiles */

.leaflet-container .leaflet-overlay-pane svg,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-marker-pane img,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-shadow-pane img,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-tile-pane img,
.leaflet-container img.leaflet-image-layer,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-tile {
  max-width: none !important;
  max-height: none !important;
}

.leaflet-container.leaflet-touch-zoom {
  -ms-touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
}

.leaflet-container.leaflet-touch-drag {
  -ms-touch-action: pinch-zoom;
  /* Fallback for FF which doesn't support pinch-zoom */
  touch-action: none;
  touch-action: pinch-zoom;
}

.leaflet-container.leaflet-touch-drag.leaflet-touch-zoom {
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  touch-action: none;
}

.leaflet-container {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.leaflet-container a {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(51, 181, 229, 0.4);
}

.leaflet-tile {
  filter: inherit;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.leaflet-tile-loaded {
  visibility: inherit;
}

.leaflet-zoom-box {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 800;
}


/* workaround for https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=888319 */

.leaflet-overlay-pane svg {
  -moz-user-select: none;
}

.leaflet-pane {
  z-index: 400;
}

.leaflet-tile-pane {
  z-index: 200;
}

.leaflet-overlay-pane {
  z-index: 400;
}

.leaflet-shadow-pane {
  z-index: 500;
}

.leaflet-marker-pane {
  z-index: 600;
}

.leaflet-tooltip-pane {
  z-index: 650;
}

.leaflet-popup-pane {
  z-index: 700;
}

.leaflet-map-pane canvas {
  z-index: 100;
}

.leaflet-map-pane svg {
  z-index: 200;
}

.leaflet-vml-shape {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}

.lvml {
  behavior: url(#default#VML);
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}


/* control positioning */

.leaflet-control {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 800;
  pointer-events: visiblePainted;
  /* IE 9-10 doesn't have auto */
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.leaflet-top,
.leaflet-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.leaflet-top {
  top: 0;
}

.leaflet-right {
  right: 0;
}

.leaflet-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}

.leaflet-left {
  left: 0;
}

.leaflet-control {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.leaflet-right .leaflet-control {
  float: right;
}

.leaflet-top .leaflet-control {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.leaflet-bottom .leaflet-control {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.leaflet-left .leaflet-control {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.leaflet-right .leaflet-control {
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/* zoom and fade animations */

.leaflet-fade-anim .leaflet-tile {
  will-change: opacity;
}

.leaflet-fade-anim .leaflet-popup {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}

.leaflet-fade-anim .leaflet-map-pane .leaflet-popup {
  opacity: 1;
}

.leaflet-zoom-animated {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-zoom-animated {
  will-change: transform;
}

.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-zoom-animated {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.25, 1);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.25, 1);
  transition: transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.25, 1);
}

.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-tile,
.leaflet-pan-anim .leaflet-tile {
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-zoom-hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}


/* cursors */

.leaflet-interactive {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.leaflet-grab {
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}

.leaflet-crosshair,
.leaflet-crosshair .leaflet-interactive {
  cursor: crosshair;
}

.leaflet-popup-pane,
.leaflet-control {
  cursor: auto;
}

.leaflet-dragging .leaflet-grab,
.leaflet-dragging .leaflet-grab .leaflet-interactive,
.leaflet-dragging .leaflet-marker-draggable {
  cursor: move;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}


/* marker & overlays interactivity */

.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow,
.leaflet-image-layer,
.leaflet-pane>svg path,
.leaflet-tile-container {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.leaflet-marker-icon.leaflet-interactive,
.leaflet-image-layer.leaflet-interactive,
.leaflet-pane>svg path.leaflet-interactive {
  pointer-events: visiblePainted;
  /* IE 9-10 doesn't have auto */
  pointer-events: auto;
}


/* visual tweaks */

.leaflet-container {
  background: #ddd;
  outline: 0;
}

.leaflet-container a {
  color: #0078A8;
}

.leaflet-container a.leaflet-active {
  outline: 2px solid orange;
}

.leaflet-zoom-box {
  border: 2px dotted #38f;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}


/* general typography */

.leaflet-container {
  font: 12px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/* general toolbar styles */

.leaflet-bar {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.leaflet-bar a,
.leaflet-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.leaflet-bar a,
.leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
}

.leaflet-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.leaflet-bar a:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.leaflet-bar a:last-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.leaflet-bar a.leaflet-disabled {
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  color: #bbb;
}

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar a {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar a:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
}

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar a:last-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}


/* zoom control */

.leaflet-control-zoom-in,
.leaflet-control-zoom-out {
  font: bold 18px 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
  text-indent: 1px;
}

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-zoom-in,
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-zoom-out {
  font-size: 22px;
}


/* layers control */

.leaflet-control-layers {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
  background-image: url(images/layers.png);
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}

.leaflet-retina .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
  background-image: url(images/layers-2x.png);
  background-size: 26px 26px;
}

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
}

.leaflet-control-layers .leaflet-control-layers-list,
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.leaflet-control-layers-expanded .leaflet-control-layers-list {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.leaflet-control-layers-expanded {
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 6px;
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
}

.leaflet-control-layers-scrollbar {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.leaflet-control-layers-selector {
  margin-top: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

.leaflet-control-layers label {
  display: block;
}

.leaflet-control-layers-separator {
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 5px -10px 5px -6px;
}


/* Default icon URLs */

.leaflet-default-icon-path {
  background-image: url(images/marker-icon.png);
}


/* attribution and scale controls */

.leaflet-container .leaflet-control-attribution {
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  margin: 0;
}

.leaflet-control-attribution,
.leaflet-control-scale-line {
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #333;
}

.leaflet-control-attribution a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.leaflet-control-attribution a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.leaflet-container .leaflet-control-attribution,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-control-scale {
  font-size: 11px;
}

.leaflet-left .leaflet-control-scale {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.leaflet-bottom .leaflet-control-scale {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.leaflet-control-scale-line {
  border: 2px solid #777;
  border-top: none;
  line-height: 1.1;
  padding: 2px 5px 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.leaflet-control-scale-line:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 2px solid #777;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.leaflet-control-scale-line:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #777;
}

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-attribution,
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers,
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers,
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar {
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}


/* popup */

.leaflet-popup {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.leaflet-popup-content {
  margin: 13px 19px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.leaflet-popup-content p {
  margin: 18px 0;
}

.leaflet-popup-tip-container {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.leaflet-popup-tip {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: -10px auto 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,
.leaflet-popup-tip {
  background: white;
  color: #333;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.leaflet-container a.leaflet-popup-close-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 4px 4px 0 0;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18px;
  height: 14px;
  font: 16px/14px Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #c3c3c3;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: transparent;
}

.leaflet-container a.leaflet-popup-close-button:hover {
  color: #999;
}

.leaflet-popup-scrolled {
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
  zoom: 1;
}

.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-tip {
  width: 24px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.70710678, M12=0.70710678, M21=-0.70710678, M22=0.70710678)";
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.70710678, M12=0.70710678, M21=-0.70710678, M22=0.70710678);
}

.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-tip-container {
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-control-zoom,
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-control-layers,
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-tip {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}


/* div icon */

.leaflet-div-icon {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}


/* Tooltip */


/* Base styles for the element that has a tooltip */

.leaflet-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #222;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.leaflet-tooltip.leaflet-clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.leaflet-tooltip-top:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-bottom:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-left:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-right:before {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  background: transparent;
  content: "";
}


/* Directions */

.leaflet-tooltip-bottom {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.leaflet-tooltip-top {
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.leaflet-tooltip-bottom:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-top:before {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
}

.leaflet-tooltip-top:before {
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: -12px;
  border-top-color: #fff;
}

.leaflet-tooltip-bottom:before {
  top: 0;
  margin-top: -12px;
  margin-left: -6px;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

.leaflet-tooltip-left {
  margin-left: -6px;
}

.leaflet-tooltip-right {
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.leaflet-tooltip-left:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-right:before {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.leaflet-tooltip-left:before {
  right: 0;
  margin-right: -12px;
  border-left-color: #fff;
}

.leaflet-tooltip-right:before {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-right-color: #fff;
}


/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.map-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant@latest/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js"></script>


<div class="map-container" id="mapid"></div>

<ul class="plot">
  <li class="markers" data-lattitude="-40.99497" data-longitude="174.50808">Text 1</li>
  <li class="markers" data-lattitude="-41.30269" data-longitude="173.63696">Text 2</li>
  <li class="markers" data-lattitude="-41.49413" data-longitude="173.5421">Text 3</li>
  <li class="markers" data-lattitude="-40.98585" data-longitude="174.50659">Text 4</li>
  <li class="markers" data-lattitude="-40.93163" data-longitude="173.81726">Text 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: oh wow, did not know that one simple change was the answer to my problem :)